# download sitecore support patch 451366

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

In Sitecore 8.1 update 1 there is a fix : Sitecore 8.1 Update 1 (An image’s URL became broken after changing its size in Rich Text Editor field. This has been fixed. (451366)) .
Is there a place from where I can download Sitecore.Support.451366 patch?

Dora

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixes are found on the [Sitecore kb site](https://kb.sitecore.net)

Unfortunately there is not an individual patch for [this particular issue](https://kb.sitecore.net/SearchResults#term=451366). This was a bug that was found in the 8.1 version and fixed in 8.1 Update 1.

You can either upgrade to 8.1 Update 1 or contact [sitecore support](https://support.sitecore.net) and ask that they create an individual patch for this fix. (You'll need a Sitecore account to log in to this site)

Comment: Thank you, I have already raised a ticket to them , but I thought that maybe there is also a place where I can download them directly without upgrading or contacting support for this